# How to use conditional in .ebextensions config for crontab multiple environments (AWS Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, cron, environment-variables, ebextensions

I want to add one condition in `cron.config` file. I need to check `ENV_ID` (environment id) if the environment ID is a match with **production server** then cron will set in crontab else cron will not set check.

**cron.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_remove_crontab:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
  02_test:
    command: |
      ENV_ID=`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentId" }`
      ENV_NAME=`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
  03_add_crontab:
    test:  [ $ENV_ID == "e-r19pphhp78l" ]
    command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab | crontab"
    leader_only: true
```

**crontab**

```
* * * * * wget https://example.com/cronrun.php >> /dev/null
```

Also, I check if condition but now working.

```
container_commands:
  01_remove_crontab:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
  02_test:
    command: |
      ENV_ID=`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentId" }`
      ENV_NAME=`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
      ENV_MYID="e-r19pphhp78l"
  03_add_crontab:
    command: |
      if [ $ENV_ID == $ENV_MYID ] then
        "cat .ebextensions/crontab | crontab"
      fi
    leader_only: true
```

I am not able to found what missing and what's the wrong script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I set all environments value in Elastic Beanstalk. Below is setup

AWS console =>Open `Elastic Beanstalk`. Select the application and go to one of environment. There we can see all the environments names, in that we need go inside the `Configuration`", after that go to the software section and click on modify. Look for environment specific `ENV_TYPE` values, which specifies whether it is a dev, stage, demo or prod, etc. The example below uses `ENV_TYPE` for the explanation. You can create your variable as you need and name it.

Now we need to open `cron.config` file inside `.ebextensions` folder and add condition.

```
container_commands:
  01_remove_crontab:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
  02_add_crontab:
    command: 'if [ "$ENV_TYPE" == "production" ]; then sudo cat .ebextensions/crontab | crontab; fi'
    command: 'if [ "$ENV_TYPE" == "development" ]; then cat .ebextensions/crontabdev | crontab; fi'
    command: 'if [ "$ENV_TYPE" == "staging" ]; then cat .ebextensions/crontabstag | crontab; fi'
    leader_only: true
```

For more details please check this link:- 
http://www.smalldaytech.com/conditional-aws-elastic-beanstack-cron-job-for-multiple-environments/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both `test` and `leader_only` simultaneously in `container_commands`, and if you do the `leader_only` will take precedence.

[elastic beanstalk docs on container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)

> A command can be leader-only or have a test, but not both (leader_only takes precedence).

Comment: I want to add this condition. how can I do?